# convert 2d string array to 1D float ,int arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, atoi, atof

For a project I want to read the columns of a text file in different arrays. First I read the file in one 2D string array and split this array in different `int` or `float` 1D arrays. But when I convert the numbers to `int` of `float` with the `atof` or `atoi` method, I got a segmentation fault. Does anyone have another solution?

```
void Tftdiag::readFile(std::string file)
{
   string testline;
   char tab2[1024];
   strcpy(tab2, file.c_str());
   ifstream Test( tab2 );
if (!Test)
{
    cout << "There was an error opening the file.\n";
}
//store words in array
int x=0,y=0;
while( Test>>testline )
{
    word[y][x]=testline;
    x++;
    if (testline=="")
    y++;
}
//output whole array with array position numbers for each entry
cout<<"Array contents:\n";
for (int y=0;y<50;y++)
{
    for (int x=0;x<6;x++)
    cout<<word[y][x]<<"("<<y<<","<<x<<")"<<endl;
}
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {

   voltage[i]= atof("0.5".c_str());
   //currentArray[i]= atof(word[50][1].c_str());
   //lux[i]= ::atof(word[50][2].c_str());
   //red[i]= atoi(word[50][3].c_str());
   //green[i]= atoi(word[50][3].c_str());
   //blue[i]= atoi(word[50][3].c_str());
}
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `std::stoi()` instead of `atoi()`. Try it, maybe it helps you

Comment: `word` has for its first dimension a size of 50. So you can only access elements until `size - 1` (49).

Comment: The expression `"0.5"` is not an object, you can't use member function on it, so that should give you a compiler error. In fact, a string literal like `"0.5"` will give you a pointer to the first element, of type `char const*`, exactly what `atof` wants so there's no need to use any wrapping into a `std::string` object.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i have changed the line to 'voltage[i]=atof(word[50][0].c_str())' but i have still the segmentation fault.

Comment: @BlitzRakete the index of the for loop goes max. to 49

Comment: @josejos41 but you are accessing element 50 `red[i] = atoi(word[50][3].c_str());`

Comment: First of all you need to run in a debugger, to locate where the crash happens. If it's not in your code you should walk up the function call stack until you are in your code, there you should look at the values of all involved variables to make sure they are okay. If you still can't figure it out you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, run it in the debugger to locate the crash in your code, and tell us where it happens and what the values of all involved variables are.

Comment: @DimChtz i have tried you solution but i got the error '‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’' with the stoi method

Comment: @josejos41 Did you include the string header?

Comment: @BlitzRakete ok sry , that was the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have run a debugger and i got a error by index 0 wit the value "7,701" and with the follow line.

voltage[i]= atof(word[50][0].c_str());